# How do I adapt the presented C# code (for splitting a string by length, relative to space) to Java, using a yielder library?

Tags: java, c#, yield-return

I came across [the below code in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18396671/2225787) to [a question on splitting strings by length, relative to the nearest space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396188/string-split-by-length-and-split-only-by-nearest-space), in which the solution is given in C#, which uses `yield return`. However, I'm looking for a Java solution, so can't use `yield return`. (Although there is a [`yielder` library](http://chaoticjava.com/yielder/api/), I'm not sure how to use it in adapting the C# code.)

The C# code, by Dmitry Bychenko, is below:

```
// Enumerate by nearest space
// Split String value by closest to length spaces
// e.g. for length = 3 
// "abcd efghihjkl m n p qrstsf" -> "abcd", "efghihjkl", "m n", "p", "qrstsf" 
public static IEnumerable<String> EnumByNearestSpace(this String value, int length) {
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    yield break;

  int bestDelta = int.MaxValue;
  int bestSplit = -1;

  int from = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i) {
    var Ch = value[i];

    if (Ch != ' ')
      continue;

    int size = (i - from);
    int delta = (size - length > 0) ? size - length : length - size;

    if ((bestSplit < 0) || (delta < bestDelta)) {
      bestSplit = i;
      bestDelta = delta;
    }
    else {
      yield return value.Substring(from, bestSplit - from);

      i = bestSplit;

      from = i + 1;
      bestSplit = -1;
      bestDelta = int.MaxValue;
    }
  }

  // String's tail
  if (from < value.Length) {
    if (bestSplit >= 0) {
      if (bestDelta < value.Length - from)
        yield return value.Substring(from, bestSplit - from);

      from = bestSplit + 1;
    }

    if (from < value.Length)
      yield return value.Substring(from);
  }
}

...

var list = data.EnumByNearestSpace(150).ToList();
```

My Java code is below, but it is not correct. (It splits only the first line, but instead of subsequent lines I get one long line.)

```
public static List<String> splitStringByNearestSpace(String text, int length) {
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (null != text && !text.isEmpty()) {
      int bestDelta = Integer.MAX_VALUE, bestSplit = -1, from = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char ch = text.charAt(i);
        if (ch == ' ') continue;
        int size = (i - from);
        int delta = (size - length > 0)? size - length : length - size;

        if (bestSplit < 0 || delta < bestDelta) {
          bestSplit = i;
          bestDelta = delta;
        } else {
          parts.add(text.substring(from, bestSplit - from));
          i = bestSplit;
          from = i + 1;
          bestSplit = -1;
          bestDelta = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
      }

      // String's tail
      if (from < text.length()) {
        if (bestSplit >= 0) {
          if (bestDelta < text.length() - from) {
            parts.add(text.substring(from, bestSplit - from)); // should yield return
            from = bestSplit + 1;
          }

          if (from < text.length()) {
            parts.add(text.substring(from)); // should yield return
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return parts;
  }
```

Test invocation:

```
String lipsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "
  + "Aliquam nec ultrices tellus. Vivamus accumsan justo in orci fermentum "
  + "maximus. Cras id condimentum felis, iaculis finibus sapien. Fusce tempor,"
  + " lectus id hendrerit interdum, mauris ex ultrices leo, et mattis nibh "
  + "purus sit amet leo. Etiam ac dolor lorem. Morbi odio ligula, ultrices "
  + "vitae risus id, pretium iaculis odio. Curabitur vel sapien tristique, "
  + "dictum sapien ut, dignissim felis. Aliquam iaculis fermentum mattis.";

List<String> chunks = splitStringByNearestSpace(lipsum, 78);
if (chunks.size() > 0) {
  for (String s : chunks) {
    System.out.println(s + " => " + s.length());
  }
} else {
  System.err.println("No chunks returned!");
}
```

Comment: return the whole list instead of yielding it

Comment: @Cid I'm not sure that will work. I suspect it will return an empty list or the first line that gets split, rather than all the chunks.

Comment: Then if you aren't sure, try it?